# Create a Dictionary in xaml?

Tags: xaml, dictionary, key-value, idictionary

Pseudo example:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Tag>
    <x:Dictionary KeyType="{x:Type sys:String}" ValueType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
        <sys:DictionaryEntry Entry="{sys:DictionaryEntry Key0, 000}"/>
        <sys:DictionaryEntry Key="key1" Value="111"/>
        <sys:DictionaryEntry>
          <sys:DictionaryEntry.Key>
            <sys:String>Key2<sys:String>
          </sys:DictionaryEntry.Key>          
          <sys:DictionaryEntry.Value>
            <sys:Int32>222</sys:Int32>            
          </sys:DictionaryEntry.Value>
        </sys:DictionaryEntry>
    </x:Dictionary />    
  </Window.Tag>
</Window>
```

Comment: More up-to-date discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494823/binding-dictionaryt-to-a-wpf-listbox

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't use the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class directly in XAML, because there's no way to specify the generic type arguments (it will be possible in the next version of XAML, but it won't be supported in VS2010 WPF designer... at least not in the initial release).

However, you can declare a non-generic class that inherits from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and use it in XAML.

**C#**

```
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, int> { }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Tag>
    <local:MyDictionary>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="key0">0</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="key1">111</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="key2">222</sys:Int32>
    </local:MyDictionary />    
  </Window.Tag>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is meant by *it will be possible in the next version of XAML* do you have any clue when they plan to implement it?

Comment: @Shimmy : actually, it is already implemented in XAML 2009. Unfortunately VS2010 doesn't support XAML 2009 yet :(

Comment: For details, see this video : http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL36/ (XAML 2009 new features are presented starting at 7'20)

Comment: what do you mean 7'20, is this when I will be 70yo :{

Comment: I mean at the position "7 minutes and 20 seconds" in the video

Answer (score 8):

If the keys and values are strings, you can use ListDictionary or HybridDictionary.

For example:

```
<Specialized:ListDictionary x:Key="MasterSlidesFileNames">
    <System:String x:Key="long">Ya long yes ni</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="Sun">Waterfall</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="lorem ipsum">hello wOrld</System:String>
</Specialized:ListDictionary>
```

Comment: Namespace declaration: `xmlns:Specialized="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Specialized;assembly=System"`

Comment: and `xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: This is maybe not such a good idea. In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0 it says: "Recommended for collections that typically include fewer than 10 items."

Answer (score 5):

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448984/) i gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449614/546730) which shows how one could create a generic dictionary in XAML without the XAML 2009 features using a custom [Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) instead.

Comment: I checked it. Yes it's great!

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

use this namespace: `xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"`

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <collections:ArrayList>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="0" Value="Standby"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="1" Value="Maintenance"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="2" Value="Available"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="3" Value="Deselected"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="4" Value="Input Error"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: New answer to an old post, but exactly what I needed.

Comment: Does this avoid duplicated keys? My guess is "no" :)