# Binding Dictionary<T> to a WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Given a dictionary of `<string, Drink>`, how would you bind the `dictionary.Values` to a WPF ListBox, so that the items use the `.Name` property?

```
struct Drink
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Popularity { get; private set; }

    public Drink ( string name, int popularity )
        : this ( )
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Popularity = popularity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Setting the `ItemsSource` on an items control creates a binding to the enumerator for the source object.  The enumerator of a `Dictionary<T1, T2>` is of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>`.  So in your item template, you can bind to the `Key` and `Value` properties, and use the path syntax to get specific properties of the key and value.

Here's an example.  First the code that creates and populates the dictionary and adds it to the resource dictionary (there are lots of different ways you can expose the dictionary to data binding; this one's simple):

```
namespace WpfApplication17
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            Dictionary<string, Drink> d = new Dictionary<string, Drink>();
            d.Add("A", new Drink("Nehi", 0));
            d.Add("B", new Drink("Moxie", 1));
            d.Add("C", new Drink("Vernor's", 2));
            d.Add("D", new Drink("Canfield's", 3));

            Resources["Drinks"] = d;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class Drink
        {
            public Drink(string name, int popularity)
            {
                Name = name;
                Popularity = popularity;
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Popularity { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the XAML for populating a `ListBox` (though a `ListView` would be easier, because you wouldn't have to define a template this complicated to make it look nice):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication17.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Drinks}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Popularity" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Key}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Value.Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Value.Popularity}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The XAML for a `ListView` is a lot simpler, and displays more nicely to boot:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Drinks}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Key"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Popularity"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.Popularity}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

To answer your follow-up questions:

I recommend Adam Nathan's *Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed*.  The chapter on layout with panels explains how the Grid works in considerable detail.  The `Grid`'s pretty counter-intuitive in a lot of ways.  You think that you'd want to create a single `Grid` that contains many items, but the number of rows and columns in a `Grid` isn't dynamic. So what you do instead is create a `Grid` for each item, and then use the shared-size functionality to make sure that the columns in each `Grid` are the same size. The `ListView` has quirks of its own, but it's a lot more straightforward for the common "display multiple items in a grid" use case.

`DynamicResource` is a markup extension that works a lot like `StaticResource`.  The difference is that when the XAML parser resolves `StaticResource` as it parses it - if the referenced resource isn't in the resource dictionary, it throws an exception. `DynamicResource` resolves the reference if the item gets added to the dictionary later. There's a bit of a performance cost to this, but it's negligible in most cases. The code I posted works if you use `StaticResource`, because the XAML gets parsed in `InitializeComponent`.  But I don't like having to remember that, so I use `DynamicResource` by default if I'm binding to something that I'm adding to the resource dictionary in code and just don't worry about whether it's being created before or after the XAML gets parsed.

And as for the toolbox:  Maybe I'll start using that in VS2010, but I find the one in 2008 unusably buggy. And not very useful anyway. I do almost all of my layout work in the editor, and some in Kaxaml.  I think the visual editor in 2008 actually made learning WPF *harder*, because it imposed an abstraction layer between me and the XAML (which is itself an abstraction layer between me and the WPF object model). And it's not a very good abstraction layer: the design decisions that went into deciding what should be hidden and what should be visible aren't, it seems to me, the right ones. Also it's buggy as hell.

Comment: Thanks Robert, you are awesome. It really works great. I am very new to wpf so this is very useful to me to try to understand. I have a few questions if you don't mind. 1. How do you find more info about the xaml syntax? For instance what's DynamicResource, Grid.IsSharedSizeScope, SharedSizeGroup, etc? Also I noticed when I first create a control by dragging from the toolbox, I get something like: <ListView ... </> so I need to type </ListView>
to insert new lines into it. Is that normal? Maybe that doesn't happen if you type everything instead of using the toolbox.

Comment: +1 for a well explained follow up. And a nice example as well ;)

Comment: Thanks Robert, you are such a great teacher. I wish I could learn these kind of insiders for new things that I want to learn. If I could give you more points, I certainly would.

Comment: One of the primary ways I've learned all this stuff is by answering questions on SO.  Someone asks a question that I know maybe half the answer to, and I put the time into figure the other half out, and now I understand the subject better than I did at first.  Different people learn things in different ways, of course, but this one really works for me.  Like, two weeks ago I didn't have any idea how to use `ListView`, but someone asked a question about it, and, well, now I do.

Comment: Good idea Robert. I am the opposite, I learn by asking (lots) of questions :O

Answer (score 3):

`ListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";`

That will tell the listbox to use the 'Name' property of the DataContext

Comment: I read his question as to say he is going to bind directly to dictionary.Values which would just be IEnumerable<Drink>, if you bind to the whole dictionary then that's correct.

Comment: Yeah just .Values. But is the above code enough for binding it? Can you please post xaml for this, as this is what I am trying to learn. Thanks.