# Binding a Dictionary with its Key and the members of its Value

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to bind a `Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass>` as ItemSource for a StackPanel using a `DataTemplate`. It works with a `Collection<DateTime>` but can't seem to get the hand of the syntax for the Dicitonary.
The xaml file below works if I just bind the Key of the Dictionary which is of type `DateTime`. But I want to access the Value too. The Value is of type MaClass and I need to put the various members (`FromDate`, `ToDate`) in the Grid as well. Thanks in advance you guys!

.xaml File

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Mytemplate" DataType="x:Type local:MyClass">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Key}"
               ContentStringFormat="{}{0:dd.MM  ddd}"/> 
        <!--Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value.FromDate}"
                  ContentStringFormat="{}{0:HH:mm}"/--> 
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thispage,Path=MyDictionary}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Mytemplate}" />
```

MyClass:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
     public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
     public string ThisString { get; set; }
     public MyClass()
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM ? If the MyDictionary property is of type `Dictionary<DataTime, MyClass>`then your template is wrong since you specified DataType as `x:Type local:MyClass`. And why do you use `ElementName` in the binding of the ItemsSource ?

Comment: I am. And yes, it is of type `Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass>`.  How is the Syntax for providing a  Dictionary<> as DataType?

Comment: I think DataType is not necessary here. Your binding should work if you remove it.

Comment: @tzippy don't know how much you simplified your code but `FromDate`, `ToDate` and `ThisString` look like public fields and you cannot bind to fields. It's not a valid [binding source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx). If that's the case you need to convert to public property by adding `{ get; set; }` for example

Comment: @tzippy dkozl is right, you have to use property instead... You also may want to have a look to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2495488/4668080

Comment: @dkozl Thank you, I changed them to public properties!

Comment: @tzippy in such case `{Binding Value.FromDate}` should work just fine

Comment: @tzippy still your `DataType` is pretty much useless, either remove it or see the custom `Dictionary` implementation in my answer.

Comment: @Staeff I did remove it. Still I thought I'd not delete it from the question not to make your comments pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you have to fix your `MyClass` to use Properties instead of Fields, because you can not have a data binding to Fields.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public string ThisString { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Afterwards just change your Template to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Mytemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                Content="{Binding Key}"
                ContentStringFormat="{}{0:dd.MM  ddd}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding Value.FromDate}"
                ContentStringFormat="{}{0:HH:mm}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

You won't have IntelliSense without the `DataType`, but to my knowledge it's not possible to define a generic `Dictionary` as `DataType` in XAML.

But to overcome this you can do an empty implementation of your `Dictionary` type.

```cs
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass>
{
}


public class Whatever
{
    public MyDictionary MyDictionary { get { ... } set { ... } }

    ...
}
```

And use your `DataTemplate` with your new `Dictionary` type:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Mytemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyDictionary}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the field issue in `MyClass` . That was the issue. Binding of `Key` and `Value.Property` is working as expected now!