# Declaring Tuple in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tuples

Is there a way to declare a tuple in xaml so I can use it as a converterparameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

There are some interesting solutions to similar questions:

- [Create a Dictionary in xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319186/create-a-dictionary-in-xaml)
- [Adding SortedList or Dictionary<int, string> to ResourceDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448984/adding-sortedlist-or-dictionaryint-string-to-resourcedictionary)

Generally, you will have to create your own type that is non-generic and use it instead.

**EXAMPLE**

For:

```
Tuple<string, int, double>
```

You could create a class:

```
namespace Models
{
    class MyData
    {
        public MyString { get; set; }
        public MyInt { get; set; }
        public MyDouble { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then add a namespace to XAML:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Models"
```

Then create your instance as needed:

```
<models:MyData MyString="someString" MyInt="123" MyDouble="0.1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to declare it in XAML. You can use x:Static to assign a ConverterParameter declared in code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={x:Static local:MyConverter.Default}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MySettings.Name}}" />
```

And what you're accessing just needs to be static:

```
public static class MySettings
{
    public static string Name
    {
        get { return "Test"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware I dont need to in fact I have this already
 Tuple<Visibility, Visibility> visibleTuple = new Tuple<Visibility, Visibility>(Visibility.Collapsed, Visibility.Visible);            this.Resources.Add("visibleTuple", visibleTuple);

just thought there had to be a way to do it in xaml with all the new features in xaml2009

Comment: Interesting side note, but doesn't answer the question.