# Blend cannot generate sample data for many intrinsic types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, blend

It looks like Blend (2015) cannot generate sample values for certain data types. The types that failed for me include `short` and `byte`. The types that generated sample values are `string`, `int` and `bool`. Has anyone else experienced it and is there a workaround for this limitation?

**Example:**

The following class doesn't generate correct sample data:

```
public partial class PointLocation
{
    public byte Number { get; set; }
    public short X { get; set; }
    public short Y { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data looks like (notice there are no sample values):

```
<VM:PointLocation>
    <VM:PointLocation.Number>
        <System:Byte/>
    </VM:PointLocation.Number>
    <VM:PointLocation.X>
        <System:Int16/>
    </VM:PointLocation.X>
    <VM:PointLocation.Y>
        <System:Int16/>
    </VM:PointLocation.Y>
</VM:PointLocation>
```

But if simply change the data type of these properties to `int`:

```
public partial class PointLocation
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

The sample data looks like:

```
<VM:PointLocation Number="79" X="30" Y="68" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing. You can manually edit the generated sample data and add values yourself.