# VS Design Time DataContext (Sample Data) Contains Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, design-time, visual-studio-designer

#### Application

It's a WPF application meant to send files between clients. I'm working on a usercontrol meant to show a list of sent files, their recipients, etc.

#### Setup

I'm trying to style the control, but I need sample data to populate it. Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48382520/1910895), I create a `SampleFilesSource.cs` that extends `DataSourceProvider`. It generates an instance of the view's viewmodel populated with an `ObservableCollection` of random recent files.

Next, in the view, I set the design time `DataContext` with this:

```
<d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <sample:SampleFilesSource/>
</d:UserControl.DataContext>
```

But nothing shows up... What happened?

#### The Data-Bound Exception

Well, let's see. The Data pane in Blend allows us to see what's in the design time `DataContext` that's available for binding. Let's take a peek.

[image: Exception inside DataContext]

Well that's interesting. There's an exception in my `DataContext`. The Data pane doesn't show you any of the values, just what fields can be bound to. So how do I get a peek at the exception's `Message`? Can I bind to it?

#### Binding To It

Unfortunately not... In fact the only binding I can get to output any text is "(Collection)", when I try `{Binding Data.RecentFiles}`. The fields are visible under the `Data` object, but nothing has any values.

But what if I set the run-time `DataContext` to the sample data generator? Just remove that little `d:` from the `DataContext` tag and debug... Still no luck. By taking a peek at the live visual tree I can see the `DataContext` is bound to an instance of the viewmodel. And interestingly enough, the only thing in the datacontext this time is an `Error` field.

There's no `Data` field at run-time and the `Error` field is an instance of `Exception`. I *think* it's null. The property explorer just has an empty box, with no options to view it. I think it's weird that no unhandled exceptions showed up in the debugging session. It got stuck in the `DataContext` somehow?

#### Debugging

So other than clean, rebuild, restart VS, restart the computer, and whatever else I had already tried, what else can I do to get a peek at that `Message`? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22608202/1910895) a handy little guide to attaching a debugger to Visual Studio's designer process. Pretty cool!

I can only learn a couple things from the debugger:

- My viewmodel being generated by my `DataSourceProvider` is valid, looks good, no exceptions thrown.
- My `DataSourceProvider`'s `Error` field is null when it leaves my code.

So all I can say that the exception occurs after I've called `DataSourceProvider.FinishQuery`, and before the designer gets it's hands on the generated `DataContext`.

#### Conclusions

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

#### Update

I created a minimum example to share, and sure enough the exception does show up in the Data pane in expression blend. However, I can actually bind to the generated sample data in the example, so now I think the exception was a red herring and my problem is elsewhere. I'm not even sure if there is an exception, and the Data pane just shows what it does because there COULD be an exception there.

[Here's](https://github.com/aurath/SampleDataException) the example if anyone else wants to peek.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show some code? 
You can look at the problem in a simple way, you can try to bind a single value. If successful, you can prove that your binding part is no problem. Then you can start with your data template.

Comment: Code's at the office, I can't get to it till Monday. But I'm sure of several things. 1. The debugger tells me that the sample data generator constructs successfully, and the `DataSourceProvider` contains no exceptions when it leaves the generator. 2. Blend tells me that it sees the generated data context, with the fields expected, and with an additional error field. But no values are accessible. When those two things hold true, the exception MUST occur after it has left my data generator, but before it's seen by the designer.

Comment: So I went a created a new project to try to reproduce the issue. The exception still shows up in the Data pane in blend, but you can actually bind to the sample data being generated. So now I suspect that the exception I've been trying to access is a red herring, and something else is throwing off my binding. I'm going to pare away the differences between the working code and mine until I figure out what is breaking it. I'd still like to know what's in that exception though. I'll post the minimum example if anyone else wants to take a look at said exception.